# Applying patch throws an error, but no .rej file created

Tags: patches, supee-7405

When I applied today's patch (https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405), it thrown this error:

> Hunk #1 FAILED at 227. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to
>   file lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej

However there is no such file called `File.php.rej`.

I am not sure what does this mean?

Comment: what version of magento? Normally when this happens it means it can't apply those changes to that file due to it being modified or not existing.

Comment: EE1.13.xx, I can confirm there is file called `lib/Varien/Io/File.php`.

Comment: Are you able to get a clean install of EE1.13 and compare the two files?

Comment: Magento team just advised to check if I have installed all previous patches. I think this is the case. Will give it try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is misleading. The patch scripts from Magento actually revert every change they made, as soon as they encounter a problem, that means:

1. no files are patched
2. no `.rej` files are created

The error you see, happens when a file is not exactly the same that the patch expects, this can mean one of these things:

1. the file was changed manually (somebody touched the core!)
2. you downloaded the patch for a different Magento version
3. you did not apply all previous patches for your Magento version

Comment: I had contacted Magento team on this and yes, it is confirmed previous patches are not installed. Thanks for more clarification on this.