# SUPEE-7405 failing to install on my version of 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

**SUPEE-7405** produces errors when applied to **Mag 1.9.1.1**.

`app/etc/applied.patches.list` displayed installed patches are:

> SUPEE-5998 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1
>   SUPEE-6237 | EE_1.14.2.0 | v1
>   SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1
>   SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 (REVERTED)
>   SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v2
>   SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1
>   SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1
>   SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1

After installing **SUPEE-7405** the following errors are displayed:

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
>   ...
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
>   **Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.**
>   **Hunk #2 succeeded at 194 (offset 2 lines).**
>   **1 out of 2 hunks FAILED** -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
>   ...
>   patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php

At around line 171, I had added `$block = false;` under **Retrieve Block html directive** section of `Filter.php`, since I was getting `ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: block` in the system.log file.  The error went away. The suggestion came from [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95394/error-message-in-system-log-regarding-undefined-variable-block-in-filter-php/96149#96149).

So I removed the above fix. (`$block = false;`), and tried to apply SUPEE-7405 again.  It now produced the following error:

---

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
>   **Hunk #1 FAILED at 171.**
>   **1 out of 2 hunks FAILED** -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers  /CustomerController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
>   patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
>   patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
>   patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
>   patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php

---

So at this time I went a head using winMerge compared the original `Filter.php` from `magento-1.9.1.1-2015-04-30-12-49-08.zip` to my `Filter.php` file.  I found the following differences.
**p.s. I have not added any of the following!**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

At this point I do not know how to apply the new **SUPEE-7405** to the site?

Comment: Would be great if you accept the answer to help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

I think your core file is changed as you have already mentioned above. I would just replace those files with fresh magento file to make sure everything is ok.

Look for these files:

1. app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
3. app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php

And take backup of these files in your local computer, then get fresh files from magento and replace in your server, then apply the patches.

After you finish, you would like to check what has been applied and change according to your backup file.

**OR**

Just replace those backed up files after applying patches and then apply patch manually to these files only.

Follow this discussion:
[Security Patch SUPEE-7405 - possible problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems)

Check this too: [Applying patch throws an error, but no .rej file created](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98249/applying-patch-throws-an-error-but-no-rej-file-created)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @rob3000 for pointing blank space in the core file, I did mentioned above that replace the file with fresh one to be in safe side.

Comment: I will do that. But first, files `patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php` and `patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php` **seemed to have patched correctly**, as there were **no errors indicated**! Is there an error that I am not seeing?

Comment: Just to be safe side, you can replace the file, but yes, you can check/compare the file to see if there is any difference. If no diff then it should be fine.

Comment: I just added the entire error to the question for your reference.  I will do that and will keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Files `Observer.php`&`Redirectpolicy.php` located at `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/` were **identical** to the original files. I did replace the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` by the original file.  But I am still getting errors: `Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.`.  Now the line number are different `Hunk #1 FAILED at 171. Hunk #2 succeeded at 182 (offset -10 lines). 1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
`

Comment: Are you able to look at the patch you downloaded and see the lines where its trying to patch for the filter.php? It could be a whitespace issue that it can't find the correct lines to change. Also are you sure you downloaded the right patch for your version?

Comment: @rob3000. Thank you again you solved my 12 hour problem.  You were correct with the blank space. There was a space on line 174, column 1 of `Filter.php` file.  Once I deleted the space, SUPEE-7405 applied without any errors to my test folder.

Comment: Thanks to @rob3000 for pointing blank space in the core file, I did mentioned above that replace the file with fresh one to be in safe side. Glad, you applied the patch successfully.